# Сохранение графика в файл с интервалами во времени

Tags: python, matplotlib, график, таймер

Есть программа, которая строит график по определенным значениям. Мне нужно, чтобы график обновлялся через определенные интервалы времени. Пытался сделать через цикл while True с таймером time.sleep(), но это не работает.

Это работает в случае с сохранением текстовых данных, тогда файл обновляется. Но в случае с графиком, файл не обновляется, пока не остановишь программу. Как реализовать обновление файла с графиком?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import datetime as dt
import time

#while True:
with open('time1.txt','r') as time1:
    tdata = time1.read().splitlines()
    print(tdata)
with open('longs.txt') as longs1:
    ydata=[int(i) for i in longs1.read().splitlines()]
print(ydata)
with open('shorts.txt') as shorts1:
    zdata = [int(i) for i in shorts1.read().splitlines()]
print(zdata)
with open('price.txt') as price1:
    pdata= [int(i) for i in price1.read().splitlines()]
    print(pdata)

#if __name__ == "__main__":
while True:
    xdata = list(dt.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") for i in tdata)
    xdata_float = matplotlib.dates.date2num (xdata)

    fig=plt.figure()
    axes1 = fig.add_subplot()
    axes1.set_xlabel('Time')
    axes1.set_ylabel('Open interest')
    axes1.tick_params(axis='x', color='b')

    axes1.xaxis.set_major_formatter (matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
    axes1.plot(xdata_float, ydata, "-o", color='g') #args: x, y, dots
    axes1.plot(xdata_float, zdata, "-o", color='r')


    axes2=fig.add_subplot(frame_on=False)
    axes2.yaxis.tick_right() #значения у на правой шкале
    axes2.set_xticks([]) # значения х отсутствуют
    axes2.plot(xdata_float, pdata, color='b')

    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.grid() #сетка
    #plt.show()
    fig.savefig('graph.png')
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, который не работает.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/G8j31A

Пока не остановишь программу вручную, график не сохраняется

Comment: Чтобы добавить код в вопрос, нужно нажать ссылку править под ним, вставить код, выделить его, нажать кнопку `{}` над редактором.

Comment: По коду - откуда у вас берутся tdata и xdata? В том коде, что вы привели, они никак не меняются.

Comment: обновил вопрос, вставил весь код